# Truncating a dataframe according to count of vector elements

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a dataframe `df`, containing three vectors:

```
subject  condition  value
01       A          12
01       A          6
01       B          10
01       B          2
02       A          5
02       A          11
02       B          3
02       B          5
02       B          9
...
```

There are four observations (and hence four rows) for subject 01, with two observations corresponding to `condition A` and two corresponding to `condition B`. Let's say that due to a technical error, there are *three* `condition B` observations for subject 02.

My question is this: how can I truncate `df` to ensure that each condition only has two observations for each individual subject (hence removing the erroneous third row where `condition==B` for subject 02)?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution -

```
df %>%
  group_by(subject, condition) %>%
  filter(row_number() < 3) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  subject condition value
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 01      A            12
2 01      A             6
3 01      B            10
4 01      B             2
5 02      A             5
6 02      A            11
7 02      B             3
8 02      B             5
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! Just as a side note, the solution provided by G. Grothendieck also works, but has to be modified if the dataframe contains other vectors that are not defined in seq = ave()

Answer (score 1):

For each subject/condition pair create a sequence number `seq` for its rows and then only keep those rows whose sequence number is less than 3.

```
subset(transform(DF, seq = ave(value, subject, condition, FUN = seq_along)), seq < 3)
```

giving:

```
  subject condition value seq
1      01         A    12   1
2      01         A     6   2
3      01         B    10   1
4      01         B     2   2
5      02         A     5   1
6      02         A    11   2
7      02         B     3   1
8      02         B     5   2
```

### Note

The input in reprodudible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "subject  condition  value
01       A          12
01       A          6
01       B          10
01       B          2
02       A          5
02       A          11
02       B          3
02       B          5
02       B          9"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE,
  colClasses = c("character", "character", "numeric"))
```